# how to check the number of entries on local member

Tags: hazelcast

my prime member

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Config config = new Config();
    config.setProperty(GroupProperty.ENABLE_JMX, "true");
    config.setProperty(GroupProperty.BACKPRESSURE_ENABLED, "true");
    config.setProperty(GroupProperty.SLOW_OPERATION_DETECTOR_ENABLED, "true");

    config.getSerializationConfig().addPortableFactory(1, new MyPortableFactory());

    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

    IMap<Integer, Rule> ruleMap = hz.getMap("ruleMap");

    // TODO generate rule map data ; more than 100,000 entries
    generateRuleMapData(ruleMap);
    logger.info("generate rule finised!");
    // TODO rule map index

    // health check
    PartitionService partitionService = hz.getPartitionService();
    LocalMapStats mapStatistics = ruleMap.getLocalMapStats();
    while (true) {
        logger.info("isClusterSafe:{},isLocalMemberSafe:{},number of entries owned on this node = {}",
                partitionService.isClusterSafe(), partitionService.isLocalMemberSafe(),
                mapStatistics.getOwnedEntryCount());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

}
```

logs

```
    2016-06-28 13:53:05,048 INFO  [main] b.PrimeMember (PrimeMember.java:41) - isClusterSafe:true,isLocalMemberSafe:true,number of entries owned on this node = 997465
    2016-06-28 13:53:06,049 INFO  [main] b.PrimeMember (PrimeMember.java:41) - isClusterSafe:true,isLocalMemberSafe:true,number of entries owned on this node = 997465
    2016-06-28 13:53:07,050 INFO  [main] b.PrimeMember (PrimeMember.java:41) - isClusterSafe:true,isLocalMemberSafe:true,number of entries owned on this node = 997465
```

my slave member

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setProperty(GroupProperty.ENABLE_JMX, "true");
    config.setProperty(GroupProperty.BACKPRESSURE_ENABLED, "true");
    config.setProperty(GroupProperty.SLOW_OPERATION_DETECTOR_ENABLED, "true");

    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

    IMap<Integer, Rule> ruleMap = hz.getMap("ruleMap");
    PartitionService partitionService = hz.getPartitionService();
    LocalMapStats mapStatistics = ruleMap.getLocalMapStats();
    while (true) {
        logger.info("isClusterSafe:{},isLocalMemberSafe:{},number of entries owned on this node = {}",
                partitionService.isClusterSafe(), partitionService.isLocalMemberSafe(),
                mapStatistics.getOwnedEntryCount());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

logs
        2016-06-28 14:05:53,543 INFO  [main] b.SlaveMember (SlaveMember.java:31) - isClusterSafe:false,isLocalMemberSafe:false,number of entries owned on this node = 412441
    2016-06-28 14:05:54,556 INFO  [main] b.SlaveMember (SlaveMember.java:31) - isClusterSafe:false,isLocalMemberSafe:false,number of entries owned on this node = 412441
    2016-06-28 14:05:55,563 INFO  [main] b.SlaveMember (SlaveMember.java:31) - isClusterSafe:false,isLocalMemberSafe:false,number of entries owned on this node = 412441
    2016-06-28 14:05:56,578 INFO  [main] b.SlaveMember (SlaveMember.java:31) - isClusterSafe:false,isLocalMemberSafe:false,number of entries owned on this node = 412441

my question is :

**why number of entries owned on prime member is not changed, after the cluster adds one slave member?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should get statics per second.

```
    while (true) {
        LocalMapStats mapStatistics = ruleMap.getLocalMapStats();
        logger.info(
                "isClusterSafe:{},isLocalMemberSafe:{},rulemap.size:{}, number of entries owned on this node = {}",
                partitionService.isClusterSafe(), partitionService.isLocalMemberSafe(), ruleMap.size(),
                mapStatistics.getOwnedEntryCount());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make use of localKeySet which returns the locally owned set of keys.

```
IMap::localKeySet.size()
```